# I need to fix the code for communicating people leaving the server and tracking their inviters Node js Discord

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I do code for New members on Discord server and it works.But i do some errors in code for leavers.What commands i need to write to do working code.

```js
//this is for new members
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    member.guild.fetchInvites()
        .then(invites => {
            const ib = inviterses[member.guild.id];
            inviterses[member.guild.id] = invites;
            const logs = invites.find(i => ib.get(i.code).uses < i.uses);
            const joinchannel = member.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "joiners");
            joinchannel.send(`${member} **join**. Inviter- **${logs.inviter.tag}** (**${logs.uses}** invites)`)
            console.log(`${member} **join**. Inviter- **${logs.inviter.tag}** inviter(**${logs.uses}** invites)`)

        });
})

// this code for leavers,it not working
client.on('guildMemberRemove', (member) => {
    targetUser = member.id
    member.guild.fetchInvites()
        .then(invites => {
            const userInvites = invites.array().filter(o => o.inviter.id === targetUser.id);
            inviterses[userInvites.id].has[targetUser.id]
            inviterses.delete(targetUser.id)
            const leavchannel = member.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "leavers");
            leavchannel.send(`${targetUser.user.username} left;Invited by ${userInvites.inviter.tag}`)
        })
})
```

Comment: what is ``inviterses``?

Answer (score 1):

Discord doesn't provide an efficient way to know who invite a member. The way you use in your case is not simple to understand for beginners.

- You fetch all the server invites (with their use count) and store them in a local variable
- When a member joins, you check which invite has its use count increased
- You update your local variable with new data

It means that if the invitation was created **after** the fetch in your local variable, you won't be able to know who invite the member. [Click here for more information.](https://anidiots.guide/coding-guides/tracking-used-invites)

To know who invited a member you need to store in a local variable (or in a database, it's better) who invited him in the `guildMemberAdd` event because you won't be able to know that in the `guildMemberRemove` event.
So tracking user invites is very complicated and difficult.